# Linked lists with more than one value per node

Tags: python, oop, linked-list, hashtable, nodes

I am trying to implement a doubly linked list with multiple variables (in this case two) per node in Python 3.

First, I created a HashEntry class for it (I'll get to make after this a hash table):

```
class HashEntry(self):
    def __init__(self, key, data, p, n):
        self.key = int(key)
        self.data = str(data)
        self.prev = n
        self.next = p
```

Then I have to use this class for my doubly linked list operations and so, but I'm not sure how to do it, if I have to create another Node class or if I to put the two values for each method
This is what I have tried:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, h = HashEntry, p = None, n = None):
    # this is where i don't know how to put my hashentry type element 
    # into the node. i was trying to make it into a single element node.
        self.element = h
        self.next = n
        self.prev = p

class Dlist(self):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.last = None

    def insert(self, e):
        aux = Node(e, None, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.last
            self.head = aux
        else:
            aux.prev = self.last
            aux.next = None
            self.last.next = aux
            self.last = aux
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Where is used the `HashEntry.key` in the `insert()` function ?

Comment: haven't used it because i'm not quite sure of how to

Answer (score 0):

Except the missing part of `HashEntry` management, the source code is showing some errors which not allow to execute the software.

**Minor Error 1** - a Python `class` doesn't inherit from `self` and it is recommended to inherit from the `class object`.

Class declaration should be:

```
class HashEntry(object):
class Dlist(object):
```

Instead of:

```
class HashEntry(self):
class Dlist(self):
```

**Minor Error 2** - a mixture between `self.head` and `self.last` when inserting the first `HashEntry` in the first linked-list.

The assignment `self.head = self.last` doesn't work because `self.last` is not initialize.

```
    aux = Node(e, None, None)
    if self.head is None:
        # self.head = self.last <= wrong assignement
        self.head = aux
        self.last = self.head # assign last based to the head
    else:
```

**Analysis 1** - add the `HashEntry` management by using the `key`.

To create a double linked-list with the simulated hashtable access, the first linked-list has to manage a kind of hashtable and the second linked-list is linked to the first to store all nodes having the same `key`.

**1-** Add to the `class Dlist` a `search(self,key)` function to check if the key of the node `aux = Node(e, None, None)` exists in the first linked-list:

> The returned value is the `HashEntry` node of the `key` otherwise
>   `None`.

```
def search(self,key):
    curr = self.head
    while (curr is not None):
        if (key == curr.element.key):
            return (curr)
        curr = curr.next
    return (None)
```

**2-** Add to the `class Node` a `append(self,nwnode)` function to add to the second linked-list the node `nwnode` having the `HashEntry.key`.

> The second list has to header the node `element`.

```
def append(self,nwnode):
    if (self.element.next is None):
        self.element.next = nwnode # adding the first homo-key
        nwnode.element.prev = self
    else:
        curr = self.element.next
        while (curr.next is not None):
            curr = curr.next
        curr.next = nwnode # adding others homo-key
        nwnode.element.prev = curr
```

**3-** Connect both functions in the `insert(self, e)` of the `class Dlist`.

> Check if the `key` is existing when the first linked-list is not
>   empty.

```
    else:
        hashnode = self.search(e.key)
```

Then insert the new HashEntry `aux` node in the first linked-list or append it to the second linked-list.

```
        if (hashnode is None):
            aux.prev = self.last
            aux.next = None
            self.last.next = aux # insert to the first linked-list
            self.last = aux
        else:
            hashnode.append(aux) # append to the second linked-list
```